# default gestures event are not working in googlemap

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

i want to add marker on the long press but my didLongPressAt coordinate event is not working. i used the print statement in it for testing. 
i have added UIView in it. I used  built in gestures too but still they aren't working. 
Here is my code. Please help me out.

```
var mapView=GMSMapView()

var camera = GMSCameraPosition()
let locationmanager = CLLocationManager()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.delegate=self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   self.locationmanager.delegate=self
    self.locationmanager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    self.locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()

}


 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    self.showCurrentLocationOnMap()
    self.locationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func showCurrentLocationOnMap()
{
    camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 15)
   mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.height)), camera: camera)



    mapView.settings.myLocationButton=true
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled=true

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position=camera.target
    marker.snippet="My Current Location"
    marker.appearAnimation=GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
    marker.map=mapView
   myView.addSubview(mapView)

}


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print (coordinate.latitude)
    print(coordinate.longitude)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are initialising mapView again by doing `mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.height)), camera: camera)`

The new GMSMapView instance's delegate that you create here is not set to self. hence the delegate method(`didLongPressAt`) is not getting called.

Instead, if you just want to reposition the camera when the current location chances, use `mapView.animate(with cameraUpdate: GMSCameraUpdate)` instead.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 15)

    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.height)), camera: camera)
    self.mapView.delegate=self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.locationmanager.delegate=self
    self.locationmanager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    self.locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func showCurrentLocationOnMap()
{
    let newLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude, self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude: longitude)
    let cameraPositionUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(newLocation)
    self.mapView.animate(with: cameraPositionUpdate)

    // Code to add the marker
}
```

Comment: mapView.animate(with cameraUpdate: GMSCameraUpdate) it's not working. it's showing an error cannot invoke animate

Comment: you need to create a instance of GMSCameraUpdate and then pass it on to this method. The code that i had mentioned above was just a prototype.

Comment: you need to do Something like this in your "showCurrentLocationOnMap"
`let newLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude, self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude: longitude)
let cameraPositionUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(newLocation)
self.mapView.animate(with: cameraPositionUpdate)`

Comment: and delete `camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 15)
   mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.height)), camera: camera)` lines

Comment: You also need to move all of these to viewDidLoad 
`camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 15)
   mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(myView.frame.size.height)), camera: camera)



    mapView.settings.myLocationButton=true
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled=true`


after this you need to have `mapView.delegate = self`

Comment: Basically, initializing the Map needs to be done only once, in viewDidLoad. Once initialized, you need to set mapView.delegate = self

In showCurrentLocationOnMap, you need to just  update the camera position. please see the code for viewDidLoad and showCurrentLocationOnMap in the edited answer

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer if it is working :)